# Kivy Button.center gives wrong value before the page is drawn

Tags: python, kivy

I have a GridLayout where I add buttons based on a json file that can change from one run to the next(so the buttons are not present in the .kv file but added in the python code, also the number of buttons can change). I want the button to have an image in the center, but accessing button.center returns junk values (both before and after adding the button to the grid layout). Instead, I tried printing button.center after the screen in question is drawn and it returns the proper value. The only solution I can think of is dynamically changing the .kv file before starting the kivy app with a bit of python code based on the data on my json but I think there has to be an easier solution.

```
for but in buttons:
  but = Button();
  but.add_widget(Image(source = "source.png", center = but.center))
  # Adds images in the bottom left corner regardless of button position
  print(but.center) # prints [50.0, 50.0] regardless of button position
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(but.center) # prints [50.0, 50.0] regardless of button position
```

No, it prints `[50.0, 50.0]` because that is the current button centre position.

You want to access the value on the next frame or later, after layout logic has been applied. For instance, you can `Clock.schedule_once(some_function, 0)` to run a function on the next frame.

Alternatively you could bind to the button position so that whenever it changes your logic runs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the first method you suggested didn't work for me I think because the first screen I draw is not the one with the buttons. On the other hand the second worked perfectly! For people interested in how to do the bind to a widget property read over here [link](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html) where it says "bind(**kwargs)"